# Can you help me identify this curved font?

Tags: font-identification

[image]

I am looking for help identifying the curved font above. Font identification sites have been no help.

Comment: WhatTheFont did successfully identify this for me, even from the curved layout. You do need to exercise some judgement in comparing its results to the original, but the right font, Copperplate Gothic Heavy, was suggested.

Answer (score 1):

It's a variant of a common font called Copperplate/Copperplate Gothic. You may even have a version of this font already on your computer. It comes preinstalled on Mac and Windows computers.

[image]

There's a higher resolution version of that [logo here](https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/614927369f334b622c88befd/32d3be36-67aa-4027-be16-fcac7098bf66/Logo+-+Colour++high+res-01.png?format=1500w) where you can see more details.